# flask not providing results to ajax call

Tags: python, html, ajax, sqlite

I am making ajax call to flask function to get data using a token as following

```
@app.route("/questgen/results", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def fetch_results():

    token = request.form.get('token')
    print(token)
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db" , timeout=20)
    cur= conn.cursor()
    select_query = '''SELECT processed, output_text 
                    FROM results 
                    WHERE token = token 
                    '''
    cur.execute(select_query)
    records = cur.fetchall()
    processed = ""
    html = ""
    for row in records:
        processed = row[0]
        html = row[1]
    conn.close()
    data = {'processed': processed, 'html' : html}
    

    return redirect(url_for('questgen', data = data))
```

ajax call is as following

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/questgen/results",
            data: { token: token },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.processed == 1) {
                    $('#divresults').html(data.html);
                    $('#divresults').show();
                    hideMyModal();
                    clearInterval(saveInterval);
                }
            }
        });
```

the complete is a bit lengthy it can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/razauh/c9a4fa84d188ac006abd113eb7a64991) the problem is that it returns

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The
> function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

even though I have tried same flask function as python function by using `return data` on the same database and it works. I have even tried to get `token` as function parameter but still it's not working. Can someone help with what am I doing wrong here? Thank you

Comment: can you explain why you do `    data_str = json.dumps(data_dict)
    data = json.loads(data_str)`

Comment: `render_template('questgen.html', data = data)` worked for me. Can you please elaborate your answer? as I have other functions in my app that use `redirect` and are returning data

Comment: I need json object of both variables

Comment: You have a dict `data_dict` you turn it to str and back again to dict - isnt it?

Comment: I deleted my first comment because I was on the wrong track.  Your `render_template` solution is the right way to handle this.  And @balderman is right: `data` is exactly the same as `data_dict`.  There is no point in converting to JSON and back.

Comment: @balderman thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `ajax` call does not handle redirects automatically.  You'll just get a response with a 301 or 302 status code.  If you really need to have it redirect, you'll need to check for a 302 status return and make the call again with the changed data.  It would be better if you could just do the redirection internally by calling the other function.

Answer (score 1):

Try jsonify to return data

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request #import this
```

And then use this to return data

```
return jsonify({"res": data})
```

In ajax you will get your data in res

```
console.log(data.res) // your data
console.log(data.res.processed) // your if condition
```

Also check whether you need to parse response body or not